Particular solutions for non homogenous linear differential equations
I have a general question regarding particular solutions for non-homogenous linear equations: Is it just a guessing game?
There doesn't seem to be rhyme or reason behind the solutions I've seen so far, it looks like pulling ideas out of thin air for $f(x)$ and i just so happens to work. What gives?
Here's an instance that I'm struggling with at the moment:
$$x^2y'' - 2xy' + 2y = 4x^2.$$

Did you try Variation of Parameters (when doing the VoP step, remember to divide by $x^2$ first? If you can guess a solution, that is great -- anything that helps find a solution and if guessing is the best approach, by all means use it as it as valid as anything else. It looks like VoP should work, there is probably a slick substitution that also works.

Sure enough, using the substitution $y = v x, y' = v + v' x$ also works. Substitute those two items, simplify and solve. This is actually easier than VoP.

There are three different approaches to particular solutions that come to mind for ODEs. I'm going to use a simpler differential equation to make my points, then relate it back to your equation in particular through a transformation and an analogous argument. Our equation will be
$$
y''-3y'+2y=4e^{2t}
$$
Method 1: Undetermined Coefficients
As the name suggests, this is glorified guessing. This is often a first approach if the solver has experience with solving differential equations and has some intuition as to how the solution should look. In general, one looks at the forcing term $4e^{2t}$ and makes an educated guess as to what sort of function may be used to generate this result. For exponentials, the general guess is
$$
F(t)=Ae^{bt}\implies y_p(t)=Ce^{bt}
$$
Basically, if the forcing function is exponential, then the particular solution is exponential, where the coefficient in the exponent remains the same but the coefficient in front may be different. This works nearly every time, but there is a fringe case to consider. When this guess is a solution to the homogenous differential equation, then we have a problem, just like we have here, since
$$
\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}-3\frac{d}{dt}+2\right)Ce^{2t}=0
$$
so there is no choice of $C$ that will work here. The modification we impose is to multiply by an extra factor of $t$, and so our particular solution is of the form $y_p(t)=tCe^{2t}$. To find $A$, we plug this into our equation and get
$$
4e^{2t}=\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}-3\frac{d}{dt}+2\right)tCe^{2t}=C\left(4e^{2t}+4te^{2t}-3\left[e^{2t}+2te^{2t}\right]+2te^{2t}\right)=Ce^{2t} \\
\implies C=4\implies y_p(t)=4te^{2t}
$$
This is all well and good as a rule to follow, but raises many questions. How did I know to guess an exponential? How did I know to modify by an extra $t$? Because that's what a thousand other mathematicians have done in the past and it seems to work out well in the end. There isn't anything rigorous about this approach; it's glorified guessing. The approach if simple:

Look at the forcing term.
Guess something similar to it (similar is not well defined, but many cases are well studied).
Modify the guess by extra $t$'s if the guess was a homogeneous solution.

Method 2: Annihilators
This approach is more structured, but still requires some a priori knowledge and trickery. This involves actually making the problem harder but removing forcing terms, solving this new problem, then backtracking to the true solution. In fact, this is where undetermined coefficients comes from in general.
Special classes of forcing terms $F(t)$ have corresponding linear derivatives that make them vanish. For instance:

$y=e^{at}\implies\left(\frac{d}{dt}-a\right)y=0$
$y=\sin(at)\implies\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}+a^2\right)y=0$
$y=t^n\implies\frac{d^{n+1}}{dt^{n+1}}y=0$

If we apply these linear derivatives to our ODE, the right hand side completely vanishes. We start with
$$
\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}-3\frac{d}{dt}+2\right)y=4e^{2t}
$$
Applying $\frac{d}{dt}-2$ to both sides, the right side vanishes, and we have
$$
\left(\frac{d}{dt}-2\right)\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}-3\frac{d}{dt}+2\right)y=0
$$
Solving for the homogeneous equation, we get that
$$
y=C_1e^t+C_2e^{2t}+C_3te^{2t}
$$
where we have picked up an extra $t$ from the repeated root of the characteristic polynomial. This solution does not solve the problem, but some constraint on the coefficients does. If you plug this into the ODE, you get $C_1$ and $C_2$ disappear, while $C_3=4$, like before.
The general approach is as follows:

Look at the forcing term.
Identify its corresponding annihilator (should one exist).
Apply the annihilator and solve the corresponding equation.
Substitute your solution into the original equation and solve for the coefficients.

This approach has more rigor, since it actually defines why undetermined coefficients works, but is more cumbersome, and there isn't always an annihilator to use.
Method 3: Variation of Parameters
This method works every time, but is computationally awful. See wikipedia for a derivation and explanation. The key here is that it works every time, but requires a lot of heavy lifting.
First, we solve the homogeneous equation
$$
y(t)=C_1y_1(t)+C_2y_2(t)
$$
Then we use the formula
$$
y_p(t)=-y_1(t)\int\frac{F(t)y_2(t)}{y_1(t)y'_2(t)-y'_1(t)y_2(t)}\,dt+y_2(t)\int\frac{F(t)y_1(t)}{y_1(t)y'_2(t)-y'_1(t)y_2(t)}\,dt
$$
That's it, that's all she wrote. The derivation involves guessing a form of the solution, imposing some conditions on parameterized functions, then solving a linear system of equations and integrating. In this case, we set
$$
y_1(t)=e^t,\;\;\;\;y_2(t)=e^{2t}
$$
Substituting,
$$
y_p(t)=-e^t\int 4e^{2t}e^{2t}e^{-3t}\,dt+e^{2t}\int 4e^{2t}e^te^{-3t}\,dt \\
=-4e^t\int e^t\,dt+e^{2t}\int\,dt=-4e^{2t}+4te^{2t}
$$
Notice that the first term can be dropped, since it's part of the homogeneous solution. You don't have to, since we are looking for a particular solution, but it isn't necessary.
Your Problem
You are faced with a Cauchy-Euler Equation. Through a transformation of $x=e^t$, your equation can be made into mine, or $t=\ln x$ transforms mine into yours. Thus, all of the rules and techniques we have used on my approaches can be used on yours as well. Some changes in guesswork include:

When using undetermined coefficients, add an extra $\ln(x)$ instead of an extra $t$ when the guess matches the homogeneous solution.
For annihilators, the algebraic operations are not involving copies of $\frac{d}{dt}$, but $x\frac{d}{dx}$ instead, which is trickier.
For Variation of Parameters, first divide by the leading function to make sure that $y''$ is by itself.

If we were using undetermined coefficients, we would guess $Ax^2$, but since this matches the homogeneous solution we instead guess $Ax^2\ln(x)$. If we used annihilators, the annihilator is $x\frac{d}{dx}-2$. If using Variation of Parameters...we crunch the numbers.
In Conclusion:
ODEs are hard to solve. We are lucky we can solve the ones we can.

If you have a right-hand side that is polynomial, sine or cosine, or exponential, then it's relatively easy to get a particular solution. Other functions? Variation of parameters will help but the integrals are not pretty sometimes.
Let's first solve the homogeneous equation $$x^2y'' - 2xy' + 2y = 0.$$ As Josh B. says in his answer, this is a Cauchy-Euler equation. These are identified when each term is of the form $x^n y^{(n)}$ where $y^{(n)}$ is the $n$-th derivative. To solve these, we look at the solution of the characteristic equation, formed by taking a trial solution $y = x^r.$ It can be shown that we need to solve the quadratic equation $r^2 - 3r + 2 = 0.$ Factoring quickly gives the solutions $r = 1$ and $r = 2,$ so the solution to our homogeneous problem is $$y_h = Ax + Bx^2$$ where $A, B$ are constants.
Easy part done. Now we analyze the non-homogeneous problem. Because the right-hand side is $4x^2$, i.e., quadratic type, we would want to "guess" something of the form $y_p = Cx^2.$ But this form is already built into our homogeneous solution, so we gain no new information! We need a slightly "stronger" guess, so we could try a higher-order polynomial, but we'll see this leads nowhere.
It may be easier to write this using constant coefficients - the preferred form, in my eyes. Let $t = \ln x.$ Through some work (exercise), we obtain the equivalent form $$\ddot{y} - 3\dot{y} + 2y = 4e^{2t}$$ where $\dot{y} = \frac{dy}{dt}.$ Our homogeneous solution now reads $y_h (t) = Ae^t + Be^{2t}$, and once again, guessing $Ce^{2t}$ gives no new information because that's built into the right-hand side. How do we improve our guess? Pad with an extra $t$. That is, we guess $y_p = Cte^{2t}.$ This will give us a bit more to work with. Substituting, we end up with $y_p '' = 4Cte^{2t} + 4Ce^{2t}$ and $y_p ' = 2Cte^{2t} + Ce^{2t}$, and $$-2Cte^{2t} + Ce^{2t} + 2Cte^{2t} = 4e^{2t}.$$
Stuff vanishes! We're left with $C = 4$, so after doing some back-substitution, we obtain $$y(x) = Ax + Bx^2 + 4x^2\ln x.$$
This "clever-guess-and-check" only really works when your right-hand sides are of the forms I mentioned previously. You'll learn more tricks along the way (Laplace transforms, perhaps), but for now, just try to get used to these special cases. Differential equations are tough to crack most of the time!
